# Null Pointer ObsecureSharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, android-fragmentactivity

Here is a snippet from my code to which I get a null_pointer in my android FragmentActivity at load with this, and am not sure why. It happens at final SharedPreferences.

```
public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String MY_PREFS_FILE_NAME = "check_status";
    final SharedPreferences _prefs = new ObscuredSharedPreferences(this, this
            .getApplication().getApplicationContext()
            .getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
    public static Context _appContext;
    private ListView _baseDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout _baseDrawer;
    private CustomActionBarDrawerToggle _baseDrawerToggle;
    private String[] _menuItemsControl;// for profile and settings.
    private String[] _menuItemsControlSplit_1;
    private FragmentManager _fManager;
    private LoginFragment _loginFragment;
    private MainDisplayFragment mf;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        _fManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mf = new MainDisplayFragment();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_drawer);

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        _baseDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        _baseDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        initlize_menu();
```

I am just trying to store a status that I wanted, securely, and thought this would be the best way.

Here is the exception:

```
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.development/com.development.BaseActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at com.development.BaseActivity.<init>(BaseActivity.java:52)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
11-05 06:37:31.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13674):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: could you post your exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to move,

```
_prefs = new ObscuredSharedPreferences(this, this
        .getApplication().getApplicationContext()
        .getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
```

into OnCreate, this piece of code is invoked before the constructor of BaseActivity, so the initialization of BaseActivity may not be done when you access this or this.xxx

Comment: I was able to get it to load using that, it no longer could be a final (obviously) but, I think there may be a better way of going about it even yet, but this essentially was the solution, thank you.